# Best Ubuntu File Search Software?

Tags: files, crash, search

I have 97,000 files 140gb (.epub books) in one folder, on a usb 3.1 external SSD, sometimes I can't even open this folder in ubuntu, just this folder, all other stuff store there opens and works fine.

I need to work whit that folder just the way it is, search, rename, organize by date, name etc (things that windows can do easy, I'm running from windows, first time living for good in ubuntu)

Is there a way to do this only whit default Gnome file manager or I have to install third part software to do this?
Ill really appreciate any ideas.

SETUP
Ubuntu 20.10 (updated)
Gnome Files 3.38.1-stable
External SSD 2TB SandDisk 3D PRO

Ubuntu System (all drivers good)
1tb NVME WD BLACK
Core I7 7700hq
32gb RAM
GTX 1060 mobile

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `find` is your friend.  It takes a while to learn though.

Comment: Opening a directory with 97,000 files in a GUI file manager requires the file manager to do "what is this file's icon; pack it into the display; resize display if necessary" Ninety-seven Thousand times! `find`, `xargs`, and the command line, are the way to handle this many files. Read `man find xargs`.

Comment: Many thanks, Ive just found "catfish" and works great, also, just change some gnome files settings and stop crashing the system, is slow but now I can open this folder, now Im reading about "find" and "xargs".

Comment: Double Commander or Krusader may do the job nice too.